# How to write greek letters in BibTeX entry?

Tags: bibtex, lyx, greek

I'm a LyX user.

I have an article title with the following text:

β-glucosidase

I have this entry in BibTeX so I tried to type `\beta-glucosidase` or `{\beta}-glucosidase` but they don't work. I tried many research on internet and this website, I can't find out why the command `\beta` does not work. I do not want that it appears in italic like `{$\beta$}`

Any suggestion?

Comment: Add `\usepackage{textgreek}` to the preamble and use `$\textbeta$`? Edit: `\beta` works only in math mode.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. -- does `\textbeta` really need to be treated as math (enclosed in `$` signs)?  i think it will work that way, but that the `$` signs aren't needed.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Oops, you're right. I changed my comment from `upgreek`/`\upbeta` to `textgreek`/`\textbeta`, and forgot to remove the `$`. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

`\beta` is a math-mode only macro, so it cannot be used in text mode. There are a couple packages which provides upright Greek letters.

- `upgreek` defines `\upalpha`, `\upbeta` etc. which are meant to be used in math mode, i.e. `$\upbeta$`.
- `textgreek` defines `\textalpha`, `\textbeta` etc. which are meant to be used in text mode.

In your `.lyx` file, go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble, add

```
\usepackage{textgreek}
```

and in the `.bib` file, write `\textbeta`. Alternatively, add `\usepackage{upgreek}` and write `\upbeta`.

The latter option has a heavier beta, so use whichever you prefer:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upgreek,textgreek}
\begin{document}
$\beta$ -- \verb|\beta|

$\upbeta$ -- \verb|\upbeta|

\textbeta{} -- \verb|\textbeta|

\end{document}
```