# How to insert capital Greek letters via bibtex entry?

Tags: bibtex, lyx, greek, capitalization

I followed advice in "[How to write greek letters in BibTeX entry?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150685/how-to-write-greek-letters-in-bibtex-entry)". I  produced a correct bibliography item based on using \textalpha in the relevant BibTeX item. (I use LyX Version 2.2.1 and I use JabRef 4.1 for Windows 10.) Regarding my use of \textLambda (in a different BibTeX item), LyX produced (in my bibliography) a lower-case lambda . How can I get LyX to produce upper-case Greek letters in my document's bibliography?

Comment: Perhaps your bib-style is to blame and lowercase the title, but without code to reproduce the problem it is rather impossible to say something definite.

Comment: Ulrike Fischer - You may be pointing me in a good direction, but I do not know enough to know for sure. In the bibliography that LyX outputs, the only capital letter for an article title is the first letter in the title. So, the problem may be 'something other than related to trying to express Greek characters.' I see that I have been using Bibliography > Bibliography Generation > Processor: > Default (and not biber, bibtex, or bibtex8). Do you think one of these three other choices might work? And, if so, which one? And, what Options: might I need to select or type in? Much appreciated.

Comment: I don't use lyx and have no idea what it does when you click on menus. Try to create a minimal example by exporting the code.

Comment: Ulrike: Thanks for your suggestion. I decided (for now) to add, via the Notes field in JabReb, a note that appears in the bibliographical item that LyX outputs. In the Notes field, I put "[[uppercase lambda]] denotes \textLambda". I use the string "[[uppercase lambda]]" in the JabRef Title field. Whereas using \textLambda fails in the Title field, using it in the Notes field works. (While I might want to pursue your recommendation later, I currently think I do not know how to 'export [relevant] code.' So, let me just leave this (for now) with this 'thank you to you' statement.)