# How to use Greek letter in bibliography title of bib file in texlive

Tags: bibtex

I use texlive 2018 and texstudio as editor, I want to use Greek letter in bibliography title using `biblatex` package, however the Greek letter such as β disappear when the file is compiled. Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks.

[tried solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150685/how-to-write-greek-letters-in-bibtex-entry) is tested.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{ctexart}
%\usepackage{upgreek}

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,url=false,doi=false,
gbstrict=true,
isbn=false,style=gb7714-2015,giveninits=false,gbnamefmt=lowercase]{biblatex}
\addbibresource[location=local]{bibtex.bib}
%\usepackage{upgreek}


 \begin{document}

%\maketitle
\cite{li_2016}

\section{}


\printbibliography[heading=bibliography,title=参考文献] 
\end{document}
```

bib file

```
@article{li_2016,
  langid = {中文;},
  title = {高压脉冲电场对β-乳球蛋白结构和抗原性的影响},
  volume = {42},
  issn = {0253-990X},
  url = {http://www.cnki.net/KCMS/detail/detail.aspx? },
  abstract = {采用的新方法。},
  number = {5},
  journaltitle = {食品与发酵工业},
  urldate = {2017-08-09},
  date = {2016},
  pages = {62-67},
  keywords = {已读},
  author = {涂, 宗财 and 李, 雪 and 王, 辉 and 杨, 文华 and 田, 明 and 马, 达},
  file = {E:\\Jianguo\\ref响.pdf}
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `title = {高压脉冲电场对$\beta$-乳球蛋白结构和抗原性的影响}`? Or `title = {高压脉冲电场对 \textbeta-乳球蛋白结构和抗原性的影响}` with the `textgreek` package?

Comment: Using textgreek prompted This NFSS system isn't set up properly. \begin{document}

Comment: Is there an universal solution to this issue which needn't change the bib file.

Comment: I already have problems compiling `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{ctexart}

\begin{document}
高压脉冲电场对β-乳球蛋白结构和抗原性的影响
\end{document}` so I doubt this is a bibliography problem. It's a general problem of `ctexart`'s handling of Unicode betas.

Comment: hzzmail<hzzmail@163.com> suggested use an unicode font for bibliography, which is a solution.
`{ \newcommand{\ftcmu}{\fontspec{CMU Serif}\selectfont} 
 \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\ftcmu}%设置英文字体不影响中文字体 
 \printbibliography[heading=bibliography,title=参考文献] 
} `

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer below so other people can find it more easily and can benefit from it. You may also want to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hzzmail suggested use an unicode font for bibliography, which is a solution.

`{ 
\newcommand{\ftcmu}{\fontspec{CMU Serif}
\selectfont} \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\ftcmu}%设置英文字体不影响中文字体 \printbibliography[heading=bibliography,title=参考文献]

}`

or add the following in preamble, which is suggested by hohos in a [Chinese forum](http://bbs.ctex.org/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=155193&page=1&extra=#pid550927).

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setmathfont[AutoFakeBold]{Libertinus Math}
```